# DOS Batch Script - Renaming directories to the date of their most recent file

Tags: batch-file

Here's my situation.  I have a few hundred folders (under Windows XP),
each of which contain several .jpgs.  The names of the folders all
got messed up when I accidentally selected all of the folders in the 
process of renaming one of them.

What I'm setting out to do is write a DOS Batch script which will
iterate through each folder, determine the modification date of the
newest file within the directory & rename the folder to that date in 
YYYY-MM-DD format.  Hence:

```
Directory of C:\Work_Area\Messed_up_dir_name

07/11/2012  10:01 AM    <DIR>          
07/11/2012  10:01 AM    <DIR>          
03/10/2008  11:00 AM           176,640 image1.jpg
08/07/2007  02:27 PM            25,088 image2.jpg
04/12/2007  04:52 PM           132,608 image3.jpg
02/06/2007  06:11 PM            61,086 image4.jpg
```

Becomes `"C:\Work_Area\2008-03-10\"`

This is what I have written so far...

```
@echo off   
REM ITERATE THROUGH EACH DIRECTORY
FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%d in ('DIR "%ROOT%" /AD /B') DO ( 
    ECHO %%d
    cd %%d
    REM DETERMINE NEWEST FILE
    FOR /F %%a in ('DIR /O:-D /B') DO @ECHO %%~ta
    cd ..     
    REM echo Newest=%Newest%    
    REM move "%%f" "%Newest%"           
    pause   
)
```

Obviously, the slashes in the date would need to be changed to another character
in order for this to be successful.  If anyone could help me out with this, it 
would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if 2 sibling folders have the same most recent modified file date? The folders can't both be renamed the same. Also, is your date format mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code that I included echoes the date in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM format.  Having each folder renamed to a MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM AM format would work.  In this particular case, there are no duplicate files in any of the folders, so the risk of duplicate folder names is low.

Comment: `:` is not valid in file or folder names, so that would have to be changed as well (perhaps `-` or `.`). The presense or absence of duplicate file names has no impact on the risk of duplicate folder names that are strictly derived form last modified time stamps.

Comment: I meant to say that there are no duplicate files between any two of the folders. Yes, I would need to substitute the ':' with another character that can be used in a folder name.                                                               All of this aside, how could I go about with capturing the latest datestamp & renaming the folder with it?

Answer (score 3):

This script will rename the folders of a directory tree whose root is specified in the 1st argument to the script (%1). I've written the script to satisfy the requirements specified in the 2nd comment to the question.

The script as written will actually echo the rename commands that would run. Simply remove the ECHO command from in front of REN when ready to rename for real.

At least one rename will fail if sibling folders have most recent modified files with the same time stamp.

Also the script cannot rename a folder that does not contain any files.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" neq "" pushd %1
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do call :renameFolder "%%D"
exit /b

:renameFolder
pushd %1
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=/: " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
    popd
    echo ren %1 "%%C-%%A-%%B %%D.%%E"
    exit /b
  )
)
```

Comment: @Garbunkel - If your question is answered to your satisfaction, then you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark near the upper left corner of the answer. That informs other users that the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation points for taking the time to accept, and awards the owner of the accepted answer 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted per question. Once you reach reputation 15 you can also up vote any answer you find useful, as many answers as you want (including to other people's questions).